# R, Multinomial Regression: How to Find Conditional Probabilities?

Tags: r, multinomial, nnet

In `R`, given a multinomial linear logit regression, I would need to obtain the conditional probability given some values of the predictors.

For example, using the function `multinom` from the package `nnet`, imagine to have computed `fit <- multinom(response ~ predictor)`. From `fit`, how can I obtain the probability weights of the different response classes, given a certain value of the predictor?

I thought of using something like `predict(fit,newdata,type=???)`, but I have no idea about how to continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a possible solution: `predict(fit, newdata = predictor, "probs")`. In this way, I was able to find the probability weights for all the values of the predictor: every row corresponds to a certain value.